# Concurrency Exception in DataLayer

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a list of items, and for each item, I need to execute series of tasks.
For accessing data layer, I am using the following code:

```
public async Task<ExampleResult> GetExampleResultAsync(Parameter parameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))      
{
    GetCustomerResult result = null;
    OracleConnection connection = this.Database.GetOracleConnection(); 
    bool needClose = false;
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        needClose = true;
    }

    try
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            .... do the work
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (needClose)
            connection.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

however, this leads to concurrency and thus I am getting

> the connection was not closed **error**.

The possible workaround for this that I ended up is to change the way of connecting to the database. I am thinking to use new connection instance for every request and surround these instances with using statement.

This would lead me lots of work and I would like to get an idea about best practices in the field for handling concurrency issues.

**EDIT:**

my caller function is below for your reference

```
public async Task<DomainResult<IList<MbRiskDto>>> QueryAsync(Action<MbrAccountAutoMatcherQueryParameter> parameter,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    parameter(_parameter);
    var nonDeclaredMbrAccounts = await _nonDeclaredMbrAccountsQuery.QueryAsync(param => param.TransactionDate = _parameter.TransactionDate, cancellationToken);

    if (nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.IsFailed)
        nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.Errors.ForEach(error => _errors.Add(error));

    var taskList = new List<Task<MbRiskDto>>();
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 10);

    foreach (var nonDeclaredAccount in nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.Result)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

        var account = (AccountDto) nonDeclaredAccount.Clone();
        var firstAccountHolder = Convert.ToInt32(account.AccountHolders.FirstOrDefault());

        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            MbRiskDto result;
            try
            {
                result = new MbRiskDto
                {
                    KimNo = await GetKimNo(firstAccountHolder),
                    HesNo = account.AccountNo,
                    FinCode = await GetFinanceCode(account, firstAccountHolder, cancellationToken),
                    Unvan = account.SMA.Substring(0, Math.Min(account.SMA.Length, 54))
                };
            }
            finally
            {
                throttler.Release();
            }

            return result;
        }, cancellationToken);

        taskList.Add(task);
    }

    var taskResult = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    return DomainResult<IList<MbRiskDto>>.Success(taskResult);
}
```

Comment: Are you properly awaiting your calls inside the using block?

Comment: I included my caller function to original post

Comment: Don't know if the Oracle provider internally maintains a connection pool the same way that MS SQL Server does. It does then you've be better off to give open & close the connection without regard to re-using a connection. Also, not sure what the "throttler" does.

Comment: On your caller code, Task.Run will cause the code in the lambda to run on a different thread. Your code is mixing parallelism and asynchronous processing. This approach is prone to causing excessive database locking even in Oracle. I would refactor your code to simply iterate through the list and process and/or aggregate results as needed. Finally, in the foreach statement the `nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.Result` causes synchronous execution of the Task which is the worse thing you can do when running async code.

Comment: `nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.Result` is the Result object of my DomainResult Class. It is not related with Task library. `await _nonDeclaredMbrAccountsQuery.QueryAsync`does async operation. Operations that I am using on the Database side is read operations and thus I am not expecting database locks.

Comment: In that case, you should refactor your code to eliminate the `Task.Run` use. Make it simple async/await all the way through. You're also trying to re-use the database connections which may cause unexpected results if other parts of you app set different connection default then you expecting.

Comment: I am trying to understand under which case I need to use parallelism, and when I remove parallelism from my code how does my code going to work in comparison to non-async code. Do I need to understand from your comments that I **MUST** not ever use concurrency together with parallelism?

Comment: No. The problem is that the code running in a new thread thread depends on the connection in the other thread. Since all the work is being done in that new thread and you're not awaiting it, the original thread returns, taking the connection with it.

Comment: can you please check my answer? I think I property refactored it. with this refactoring, the operation takes approximately 4minutes to finish. Do you have any suggestion in order to make it work faster?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments I removed Task.Run() clause and replaced with the code below. Right now, I believe that my concurrency problems are solved.

```
Func<Task<MbRiskDto>> mbRiskTask = async ()  => new MbRiskDto
{
    KimNo = await GetKimNo(firstAccountHolder, cancellationToken),
    HesNo = account.AccountNo,
    FinCode = await GetFinanceCode(account, firstAccountHolder, cancellationToken),
    Unvan = account.SMA.Substring(0, Math.Min(account.SMA.Length, 54))
};


taskList.Add(mbRiskTask.Invoke());
```

Thus, Resulting code can be seen below

```
public async Task<DomainResult<IList<MbRiskDto>>> QueryAsync(Action<MbrAccountAutoMatcherQueryParameter> parameter,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    parameter(_parameter);
    var nonDeclaredMbrAccounts = await _nonDeclaredMbrAccountsQuery.QueryAsync(param => param.TransactionDate = _parameter.TransactionDate, cancellationToken);

    if (nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.IsFailed)
        nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.Errors.ForEach(error => _errors.Add(error));

    var taskList = new List<Task<MbRiskDto>>();

    foreach (var nonDeclaredAccount in nonDeclaredMbrAccounts.Result)
    {
        var account = (AccountDto) nonDeclaredAccount.Clone();
        var firstAccountHolder = Convert.ToInt32(account.AccountHolders.FirstOrDefault());

        Func<Task<MbRiskDto>> mbRiskTask = async ()  => new MbRiskDto
        {
            KimNo = await GetKimNo(firstAccountHolder, cancellationToken),
            HesNo = account.AccountNo,
            FinCode = await GetFinanceCode(account, firstAccountHolder, cancellationToken),
            Unvan = account.SMA.Substring(0, Math.Min(account.SMA.Length, 54))
        };
        //var task = Task.Run();

        taskList.Add(mbRiskTask.Invoke());
    }

    var taskResult = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    return DomainResult<IList<MbRiskDto>>.Success(taskResult);
}
```

**EDIT:**

With this refactoring, the operation takes approximately 4minutes to finish. Do you have any suggestion in order to make it work faster?

Comment: The speed, or lack thereof, is totally up to whatever is going on in `GetKimNo` and`GetFinanceCode`, as well as your database/network. Since tasks return hot, you still are essentially running in parallel, as each task basically running at the same time, but it still takes as long as it takes for them to do their work. Async doesn't make anything happen faster, it just uses server resources more efficiently to make it all happen. You can try combining queries, optimizing the queries, optimizing your database (both instance configuration and things like adding indexes on your tables)

Comment: On the database side, I will make the proper tuning. I just would like to make sure that my approach is now in recommended way. Thank you very much @Chris.

Comment: Well, don't get me wrong. I simply said it should achieve your goal of a degree of parallelism. There's way too many moving parts here to say whether what you're doing is in fact "good" or "recommended". However, that's out of scope for Stack Overflow, anyways. You can take your code (all of your code) over to Code Review and see if you get any bites there.